# mysqldump `--where` statement "over length"

Tags: mysql

I am using `mysqldump` with `--WHERE` condition

the problem is when I send "over length" statement to `--WHERE=` in mysqldump using windows CMD command it doesn't continue

I tried to make a cmd variable holds `"wherestatement"` and read it from file like this

```
   set /p wherestatement=<d:\test.txt & mysqldump u- user -p -h host - database mytable --where=%wherestatement%
```

It works only if not "over length" statement

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us what your WHERE statement looks like but it sounds like it exceeds the Windows maximum command line length.

Try executing `SOURCE filename.sql` where `filename.sql` contains your SQL statement to execute.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-batch-commands.html

Comment: Thank you for your response... Yes I didn't post my where statement it's too long... I will try it... Do i need to write it like this  --where=<filename

Comment: Didn't work ... I tried `--where=<filename` , `--where= SOURCE filename` and `--where=\. filename`

Comment: That's not how it works. You should invoke ``mysql -u username -pPassword dbName <filename.sql``. ``filename.sql`` needs to contain your *entire* SQL statement, e.g. ``SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE foo = 'bar'``.

Comment: @AhmedTaha What is the contents of your `filename.sql` file?